# Using streamlink to stream rtsp through vlc. When i pause the stream and then play issue

Tags: libvlc

Using streamlink to stream rtsp  through libvlc. When i pause the stream and then play, it resumes where i paused from. How do i go back to live broadcast after i pause? Right now all i can think of doing is restarting the stream.
"sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,width=600,height=480,acodec=mp3}:http{mux=mp3,dst=127.0.0.1:8080/desktop.mp3}",
":no-sout-rtp-sap",
":no-sout-standard-sap",

I tried to do it but it continues
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried seeking? Honestly besides restarting the stream completely, I'm not sure

Comment: How can i do thaT?